# Non-English text appears garbled in gVim

Tags: fonts, gvim, unicode

I'm able to input Tamil text successfully in gVim, but the output appears with letters getting one on top of another. This is the case whether I create the file from within gVim or create it elsewhere and open it in gVim.

gVim seems to give insufficient space for individual graphemes, but more importantly, its idea of dealing with combining sequences seems to be "put them on top of each other" irrespective of where they are actually supposed to be.
For eg.: ம + ெ should result in மெ as in the Notepad++ output (4th paragraph, 1st line, 5th word), but gVim seems to have dumped the ெ on top of ம and left it at that.

Is there anything I can do on my end to change this and get a proper display?

**gVim**:
[image: This is how gVim displays Tamil text]

**Same file, using the same font, on Notepad++**:
[image: Same text displayed by Notepad++]

FTR, the above screenshots were taken with font set to 'Source Code Pro' in both editors, but I've tried all available fixed-width fonts (Courier New, Consolas, GNU FreeFont, Lucida Console, etc.) in gVim with no improvement in display.

Comment: Unicode Tamil is not fully supported in many platforms primarily because Tamil is treated as a complex script that [requires complex processing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tamil_All_Character_Encoding). Ask `gvim` support or report a bug…